# Labels and images above TableView don't show up on device

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uilabel, uistoryboard

So, I've laid out a UITableViewController with two prototype cells, and a view in the TableView's header area. In the header area, there are two views that each hold an icon and a label, Friends and Groups.

It looks all good in the Storyboard Editor, but when the screen actually loads, the images and labels in question are gone. I'm fairly new to iOS, so I haven't run into this before. Here are a couple screen shots to illustrate:

In the storyboard editor:

[image]

On the simulator:

[image]

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out that this was because the tableHeaderView of a UITableView is really weird about updating/redrawing. It's very difficult to get it to act in any sort of expected behavior.

Instead of using UIImageViews, we used UIButtons. The buttons seem to know how and when to updated and redraw themselves, so that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You've implemented the data source methods in your view controller, correct?

If not, UITableView will call a method that its data source implements: `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` from the UITableViewDataSource protocol, where you would return the cell to use, in this case the cell with the Identifier that you specified in your Storyboard.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, maybe I wasn't being clear. I'm not worried about the prototype cells not showing up, I'm worried out the Friends and Groups icons and labels in the header of the table view.